# mysql stuck in inner join query

Tags: php, mysql, database-administration, mysql5

i have a mysql db with around 200 tables & each tables have around 40,000 entries.
i m trying inner join, but on xamp environment, it takes around **4hrs**... as well as on cloud it simply gives error 500 after 10 min.
here is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT od.io_id, od.io_date, sm.style_code, cm.short_name, od.cust_po, od.mepl_no, od.season, btm.cat_art_no, odd.rev_del_date, od.total_qty, od.shipping_qty, um.short_name, od.order_value_fc, od.order_value_inr, odd.ex_factory_date, od.repeat_order, ot.order_type_name, od.agent_commission AS return_bonus, cm.bonus_discount, cm.other_discount, od.status, il.short_name AS terms, delm.delivery_mode_name, c.short_name AS cur
FROM orderdetails od
INNER JOIN bomtrimqty btm ON od.style_id = btm.style_id
INNER JOIN orderdeliverydetails odd ON od.io_no = odd.io_no
INNER JOIN ordertype ot ON od.order_type_id = ot.order_type_id
INNER JOIN stylemaster sm ON od.style_id = sm.style_id
INNER JOIN customermaster cm ON od.customer = cm.customer_id
INNER JOIN unitmaster um ON um.unit_id = sm.unit_id
INNER JOIN deliverymodelist delm ON delm.delivery_mode_id = odd.rev_del_mode
INNER JOIN incotermlist il ON il.inco_term_id = od.order_type_id
INNER JOIN currency c ON od.fc_unit = c.currency_id
ORDER BY od.io_id DESC
```

even i tried

```
GROUP BY od.io_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

but no luck .... mysql doesnt give any error ..
please help me out it

Thx in advance !

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the columns you're joining by? And an index on `orderdetails.io_id`?

Comment: Agree with @Barmar - this is probably a problem related to some columns missing indexes.

Comment: I suggest the 500 error because of script time limit... Check php error_reporting settings to get more information..

Comment: Apart from the correct indexes: I don't see any limiting factors on what you're retrieving. Use multiple 'WHERE' clauses and restrict the results to only those you are actually using. A 'GROUP BY' is different since it still requires all data.

Comment: @Barmar there are no indexes

Comment: @simialbi will check & post the settings from error_reporting

Comment: @KIKOSoftware will try multiple 'WHERE' clauses

Comment: @AashishPande That will be your problem. For every join it has to do full table scans. That means it has to scan `40,000^10` rows.

Comment: Please provide the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ... `

Comment: @Barmar -- thanks for suggestion ...Indexing worked ... but still it takes 10 -15 min to fetch 40,000 records... can it be optimized further ?

Comment: Such a huge join is bound to be expensive, even with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

First you can add some indices:

```
ALTER TABLE orderdetails ADD INDEX abc (customer, style_id, io_no, order_type_id, fc_unit);
ALTER TABLE bomtrimqty ADD INDEX abc (style_id);
ALTER TABLE orderdeliverydetails ADD INDEX abc (io_no, rev_del_mode);
ALTER TABLE ordertype ADD INDEX abc (order_type_id);
ALTER TABLE stylemaster ADD INDEX abc (style_id, unit_id);
ALTER TABLE customermaster ADD INDEX abc (customer_id);
ALTER TABLE unitmaster ADD INDEX abc (unit_id);
ALTER TABLE deliverymodelist ADD INDEX abc (delivery_mode_id);
ALTER TABLE incotermlist ADD INDEX abc (inco_term_id);
ALTER TABLE currency ADD INDEX abc (currency_id);
```

then you can change the join order:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
  od.io_id, od.io_date, sm.style_code, cm.short_name, od.cust_po, od.mepl_no, od.season, btm.cat_art_no, odd.rev_del_date, od.total_qty, od.shipping_qty, 
  um.short_name, od.order_value_fc, od.order_value_inr, odd.ex_factory_date, od.repeat_order, ot.order_type_name, od.agent_commission AS return_bonus, 
  cm.bonus_discount, cm.other_discount, od.status, il.short_name AS terms, delm.delivery_mode_name, c.short_name AS cur
FROM orderdetails od
INNER JOIN customermaster cm ON od.customer = cm.customer_id
INNER JOIN stylemaster sm ON od.style_id = sm.style_id
INNER JOIN unitmaster um ON um.unit_id = sm.unit_id
INNER JOIN bomtrimqty btm ON od.style_id = btm.style_id
INNER JOIN orderdeliverydetails odd ON od.io_no = odd.io_no
INNER JOIN ordertype ot ON od.order_type_id = ot.order_type_id
INNER JOIN deliverymodelist delm ON delm.delivery_mode_id = odd.rev_del_mode
INNER JOIN incotermlist il ON il.inco_term_id = od.order_type_id
INNER JOIN currency c ON od.fc_unit = c.currency_id
ORDER BY od.io_id DESC
;
```

What does your performance say now?

Comment: while ALTER   --- 'Error Code: 1072. Key column 'rev_del_mode' doesn't exist in table'

Comment: sorry... ALTER  works fine ... but join order query took 5 hrs

Comment: WHat is the Output of `EXPLAIN SELECT yourQuery` ?

Comment: [link] goo.gl/flPlbA for output

Comment: any suggestions form `EXPLAIN SELECT` Query result?

Comment: with 'LIMIT 10' it took 4 min 9 sec ( 298.969 sec )  ... is there any way to optimized it further ?

Comment: Do you really Need all that Details for _all_ `customer_id`? Perhaps you need the details for a certain id only. If so you could split the request into two: One request querying Information you Need for all customers and the above query with an additional condition at the end: `WHERE cm.customer_id = <id>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with subquery instead of many JOINs, and keep indexes on those fields which you will use in WHERE condition, this strategy will work.